# Comparing records of the same type with = and !=

Tags: oracle, plsql, record

Is there a way to compare a self defined record structure in Oracle? I am trying with `=` and `!=` but the only thing I get is the compilation time error

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '!='

Example

```
type my_type is record (
  a varchar2(6),
  b varchar2(6)
);

rec1 my_type;
rec2 my_type;

begin
  if rec1 = rec2 then
    null;
  end if;

  if rec1 != rec2 then
    null;
  end if;
end;
```

Comment: Do they have to be records?  Object types are similar to records, except they are defined in SQL, and they allow a map function to make comparisons easier.

Comment: It would be better if they were records but thanks for the hint I will look closer at the object types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the doc:](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS496)

```
**Record Comparisons**
Records cannot be tested natively for nullity, equality, or inequality. These BOOLEAN expressions are illegal:

My_Record IS NULL
My_Record_1 = My_Record_2
My_Record_1 > My_Record_2

You must write your own functions to implement such tests. For information about writing functions, see Chapter 8, "PL/SQL Subprograms."
```

Comment: indeed, such a built-in would be nice.